# XM Cloud Sitecore Information BE

Tags: xm-cloud

not needed, please delete it thanks . asdasdasdasdsadasdsadasd

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm a .Net Backend developer too, I will share my experience in an XM Cloud project.

Definitely, you have to expand your knowledge and learn the basics of React and NextJS, hooks, and TypeScript to start working with the NextJs Starter you mentioned.

In my experience, a Frontend fellow gives me the HTML and all the styling, animations, and pretty CSS classes to make the user experience great, and we have to integrate in .tsx components that will be called in a JSON Rendering in the CMS, similar as we had before with View or Controller renderings.

As BE, if apply for your company's role, you still have to create the templates, renderings, placeholders, layouts, assign data sources, create APIs, create GraphQL queries, and of course, retrieve the data from the content items to our components.

On Github, there's the base branch of the Starter code with examples on how to work with components, here's the link:
https://github.com/sitecorelabs/xmcloud-foundation-head

And in my blog https://sitecoretek.wordpress.com/ you can find some posts that will help you and save time, for example, the initial setup of the project, working with placeholders, and work with GraphQL locally.

Hope this finds you helpful, and trust me, is a new very exciting world to work with XM Cloud and headless.

Answer (score 2):

Just to add some more context, depending on your Role on the project, as a backend developer:

- Having some knowledge about nextJs/react is a plus
- Having enough background about docker (for your local setup)
- Understanding the deployment and xmcloud deploy app
- Having knowledge about the Experience Edge
- Having good knowledge of Sitecore SXA and its architecture (Headless variant for xmcloud)
- Having good knowledge about the Sitecore CLI and Serialization and IAR deployment
- Having good knowledge about graphql query / content resolvers
- Understanding the headless architecture and the changes in xmCloud (ex. publishing)
- If you are using Vercel, of course, you need to have knowledge about the Vercel and its deployment

If you want to have a starting point please check the [Getting started with xmcloud](https://doc.sitecore.com/xmc/en/developers/xm-cloud/getting-started-with-xm-cloud.html) documentation, there are a few videos on YouTube.

You can find some information here: https://www.ashournia.com/, I recommend checking the posts about publishing and workflows.